# Cannot format javadoc html with google-code-prettify lib

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-code-prettify

I tried to add styling to a `<pre>` block using:
https://github.com/google/code-prettify

But all I see is this:

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

I am looking to get the default syntax highlighting.

I put this at the top of the html file:

and then I have a `<pre>` block that looks like so:

```
  /**
   * <pre class="prettyprint">
   * new BeanTranslator.Builder()
   *   .translate(
   *     new{@code Translator<String, Integer>}(String.class, Integer.class){
   *      {@literal @}Override
   *       public Integer translate(String instance) {
   *         return Integer.valueOf(instance);
   *       }})
   *   .build();
   * </pre>
   */
```

I inspected the html and it looks like so:

[image]

**What I doing wrong?**

Comment: Have you put the link to the library in the header of the document?

Comment: yep I sure did, but I will double check

Comment: It appears java might be converting `@code` to the literal html `<code>` tag somehow. There are 2 code tags in your `<pre>` tag.

Comment: Can you also post the full `<pre>` tag that you're using. I can't see the `public static <I, T, V, E>` ect

Comment: With Javadoc there are many many entrypoints, so I need to figure out a way to include a script tag in more than 1 index.html file.

Comment: have you tried escaping the @code tag or `&commat;` for the `@` symbol

Comment: I got it to work...thanks.. with javadoc, there are many entrypoints to the page, so I have to include the script tag in all the html files unless someone knows a good trick